# "Incorrect integer value..." error when reading .txt with Python and inserting into MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am trying to read a super simple .csv/txt file into Python and insert the data into a local MySQL database.

Here it is with Python **.csv reader** module:

```
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import xlwings as xw
import csv

# Connect to database
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "/pwd/",
    db = "mydb",
)

sql = '''INSERT INTO dimension(dimension, dimensionType, abbreviation, translationHr, code, priority) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
cursor = db.cursor()

# Open CSV, read data
with open('/users/edchigliak/desktop/baza.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

# Insert into db
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute(sql, row)
        db.commit()

sql = '''SELECT * FROM dimension'''

cursor.execute(sql)
db.close()

result = cursor.fetchall()
print result
```

This is however, giving me this error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'dimensionType' for column 'dimensionType' at row 1")

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5vgJehSVPD4ZGZYUFE2MHRhYVU) to the file that I am reading (saved from Excel 2016 for Mac as .csv, then re-saved from SublimeText as UTM-8).

If I try to do it with Pandas module like so:

```
df=pd.read_csv('/users/edchigliak/desktop/baza.txt')

for row in df:
    cursor.execute(sql, row)
    db.commit()
```

I get this error:

> query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What am I doing wrong?

- not reading .csv the right way?
- not converting the values after getting them into python/pandas?
- not inserting properly into db?

Answer (score 0):

With constructing the sql string via those % you do not get the '' around the values that are needed! You could use '{0}' and format or any sql string builder...

Comment: Ramakers thanks for the reply. I read somewhere (can't remember where) that this is the proper way to do it and MySQL supposedly handles dataType conversion?

Comment: i think your solution is just about fine if you put '%s' around your %s of the sql string.